How can we get our dApp to not have the malicious indicator?
So I know there are a couple "solutions" saying we need to reach out to Blowfish to get put on the whitelist. I did that, and they said I needed connections within the developer community before being verified. I stated that I did not have any connections as I am a new developer and asked what else I needed to do to get verified. I did not get any further response from their end.
Is the only way to get approved is to start getting to know other developers pretty much then?
The other thing they mentioned was we could use the "signAndSendTransaction" method to immediately bypass the requirement. I did try to use the method from window.solana, but it still flagged my site as malicious, so I'm not sure if I was doing it incorrectly or it just doesn't work. Has anyone been able to get this working / have any examples?
I'm just trying to release my non-malicious dApp to the public without 3 red flag click throughs for anyone to use it.
Thanks all

No way to circle around this. It's their approval. Or maybe directly reach out to phantom and Backpack that use the service, see if they have ways you can circumvent this.

@Jimii thanks for the feedback. That's pretty dumb. Sort of feels tyrannic, especially if they don't have a solid framework of how to get approved other than vaguely having connections in the industry... I'd feel a lot better if there was a set guide on how to get approved legitimately. I guess I'll have to keep emailing...

I understand your pain. The main reason wallets rely on this is to prevent users' wallets from being drained. I'm unsure if there is a better way of doing this without some centralized system like Blowfish.

I'm facing the same issue. They have review my site, and my code on I posted on github. I use the signAndSendTransaction. But because I'm not in their good ol boys club. Nor a top 10 dev in solana thats fully doxed with years of historical socialmedia posts etc, they state I must have a super well-known person vouch for me.
But with everything being open source I've never had to join communities etc. So it sounds like their policy is basically just deny anyone that wants to learn/develop on Solana. Unless you get the creator to vouch for you. Okay man. Wish solana would but this as step 0 in their development guides with big red flags saying, DO NOT ATTEMPT TO DEV on the solana ecosystem unless you get a vouch. you will waste months of time, effort and being out money for making live sites. just to be blocked!
